# Monitoring Zabbix of MongoDb Atlas Cluster

Tags: mongodb, monitoring, mongodb-atlas, zabbix

I am configuring a Zabbix service to be able to monitor every hosts and service I'm currently using.

I tried to configure without any success the MongoDb [Cluster,Node] by Zabbix Agent 2 template.

I added a specific user and pwd to allow retrieving monitoring information and typed them into the Macros informations : {$MONGODB.USER}, {$MONGODB.PASSWORD}

I also typed in the URI to connect to one of the nodes of my actual MongoDb Atlas Cluster into the field : {$MONGODB.CONNSTRING} like the example following : `tcp://clustername.instance.mongodb.net:27017`.

With all those informations, I continualy receive a message "No reachable servers" / "zabbix_get [8700]: Get value error: ZBX_TCP_READ() failed: [104] Connection reset by peer"

The "ZBX_TCP_READ" is returned when I use the :
`zabbix_get -p agent2_port -s host -k 'mongodb.ping["tcp://cluster.instance.mongodb.net:27017","zabbix_user","zabbix_password"]'`

All I can achieve is being returned a:

```
zabbix_get [7647]: Get value error: ZBX_TCP_READ() failed: [104] Connection reset by peer
zabbix_get [7647]: Check access restrictions in Zabbix agent configuration
```

I'm expecting to be retrieving a "Connection Successful" then all the informations regarding the collections, the I/O, ...

I know I can use the MongoDb Atlas Monitoring Page, but would prefer to retrieve all my Monitoring informations into a unique service "Zabbix" I'm currently configuring.

What am I missing ? Has someone already managed with success to monitor MongoDb Atlas Cluster through Zabbix (did not find something relevant in my Google Searchs, nor in Stack Overflow) ?

Thank you by advance for any help you can provide.